# Is it possible to install virt manager in client mode?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I have a KVM server (updated to Ubuntu 14.04) for several years now, that I handle distantly with virt-manager under different Linux flavours. I recently formatted and reinstalled my main workstation under Debian 8 (dist-upgrade have been a real mess). When I came to reinstall virt-manager, I realized there was a huge list of dependencies, including qemu-kvm, bridge-utils, and so on. So I canceled it. I don't want to setup a second KVM server on my workstation. And I don't want to be stuck with virsh on the command line.

Is there an easy way to install only the client part of virt-manager ?

Or maybe it is time to forget virt-manager and try an equivalent open source web manager, for example? (Names are welcome.)

Comment: Try installing with `--no-install-recommends`.

Comment: The simplest thing i wouldn't even imagine :) Can you post an answer instead of a comment ? So i could make it resolved by it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages that you do not want to install on your system are pulled in as recommended package, rather than hard dependencies. You can skip the recommends with the `--no-install-recommends` option to `apt-get`.